# Closing View Controller from Save Button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I'm having a issue in  Unwinding/Closing a View Controller.

My navigation bar in this view controller has two buttons. The left one is an "Unwind/exit" button that functions fine and closes the current view controller and returns the user back to the main setting screen. The second button is a "Save" button that commits the users data to the `NSUserdefaults`. Both buttons do what they are designed. Although I would like the "Save" button to do one more thing.

I would like the Navigation Bar "Save" button to continue to save as data as its designed, but I would also like it to "Unwind/Exit" that view controller and return to the main Settings view controller just like the "Unwind/Exit" navigation bar button does.

Here is my code for the view controller. As you will be able to see, i am calling the "backButtonTapped" function from within my "settingSaveEmailAddress" function. I know the "backButtonTapped" function is being triggered because the "print" command is printing in the debug window. Although it is saving my data, it is failing to close the view controller and unwinding back to the main settings view controller.

```
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var settingEmailAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var settingEmailAddressLastUpdate: UILabel!

    // Constant keys for NSUserDefaults look ups
    static let settingDefaultEmailAddress = "EMAIL_ADDRESS"
    static let settingDefaultEmailAddressLastUpdated = "EMAIL_ADDRESS_LAST_UPDATED"


    //End Setting - Email Address
    @IBAction func settingSaveEmailAddress(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (settingEmailAddress.text!.characters.count > 0) {
            let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            prefs.setObject(settingEmailAddress.text, forKey: SettingsViewController.settingDefaultEmailAddress)
            saveTimestampEmailAddress()
        }
        dismissKeyboard()
        print(settingEmailAddress.text)
        backButtonTapped(self)




    }
    //End Setting - Email Address


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment these if you want to clear out the saved defaults
        //let appDomain = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!
        //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain)

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SettingsViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        // update labels from NSUserDefaults
        getUserPreferences()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // Updates the view with the user values already stored in NSUserDefaults
    func getUserPreferences() {
        let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        // Get Email Address
        if let email = prefs.stringForKey(SettingsViewController.settingDefaultEmailAddress) {
            settingEmailAddress.text = email
        }

        // Get the last time something was stored
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
        if let lastUpdateStored = (prefs.objectForKey(SettingsViewController.settingDefaultEmailAddressLastUpdated) as? NSDate) {
            settingEmailAddressLastUpdate.text = "Last Update:" + dateFormatter.stringFromDate(lastUpdateStored)
        } else {
            settingEmailAddressLastUpdate.text = "Last Update: Never"
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Keyboard responders so the keyboard goes away when we're done editing.
    // Dismiss the keyboard when the user is finished editing.
    func dismissKeyboard(){
        // Resign the first responder status.
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    // Saves the timestamp of when the user has made a change to the NSUserDefaults
    func saveTimestampEmailAddress() {
        let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let timestamp = NSDate()
        prefs.setObject(timestamp, forKey: SettingsViewController.settingDefaultEmailAddressLastUpdated)
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
        settingEmailAddressLastUpdate.text = "Last Update:" + dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timestamp)
    }

    func backButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            print("Exit Triggered")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this function and I am now getting the expected functionality when I press "Save".

1. Save NSUserDefault data
2. Close current ViewController and return to
   my main settings view controller "SettingsMainTableViewController".

   ```
   func closeVCReturnSettings() {
   for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
       if controller.isKindOfClass(SettingsMainTableViewController) {
           self.navigationController?.popToViewController(controller as UIViewController, animated: true)
           break
       }
       print("Return to settings")
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can write :-

> **In Objective-C**

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

> **In Swift**

```
 func popToRootViewControllerAnimated(_ animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]?
```

at the end of your "Save" buttons method if your "Main Setting" viewController is the root viewController.

Comment: Thanks for the time, unfortunately that did not work for me. I am sure i missed something since I am new to iOS development.